# Numpy: how to vectorize a for loop generating random numbers?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Say I have the following simple function that I use to generate random numbers:

```
def my_func():

  rvs = np.random.random(size=3)
  
  return rvs[2] - rvs[1]
```

I want to call this function a number of times, lets say 1000 and I want to store the results in an array, for example:

```
result = []
for _ in range(1000):
   result += [my_func()]
```

Is there a way to use numpy to vectorize this operation and make everything faster? I don't mind if the workflow changes.

Comment: could you please give the example output you would like to have?

Comment: I’d have an array which contains 1000 random numbers that are generated from the myfunc function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you just need to use the [np.random.rand](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.rand.html) function:

```
np.random.rand(1000)
```

This function create an array of the given shape and populate it with random samples from a uniform distribution over [0, 1).

You can vectorize as follows:

```
rvs_vect = np.random.rand(10000, 3)
result = rvs_vect[:,2] - rvs_vect[:,1]
```

`rvs_vect[:,1]` selects all rows in column 1.
`rvs_vect[:,2]` selects all rows in column 2.

Execution times for instances of 10000 elements on my machine are about 100 times faster than your solution and the other proposed ones ([np.vectorize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73527378/9302488) and [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73527108/9302488)).

**Extras**

I have prepared an example for you with [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/). Numba is an open source JIT compiler that translates a subset of Python and NumPy code into fast machine code.
Although you will not gain substantial advantages over numpy on this type of operation.

```
import numba as nb
nb.njit 
def my_rand(n):
    rvs_vect = np.random.rand(n, 3)
    return rvs_vect[:,2] - rvs_vect[:,1]
```

Comment: But I’m trying to generate random numbers of size 3, and repeat this 1000 times. I’d like to have it vectorized though. The output of myfunc is a single number, I call myfunc 1000 times so I get an array of 1000 numbers

Comment: Thanks for this, just wondering, what does the comma notation mean here? I’ve never seen it before

Comment: To make it faster, you can even add numba `njit` decorator.

Comment: @skidjoe `rvs_vect[:,2]` means that you are referring all the rows in the array with the 3rd number in that particular row.

Answer (score 0):

You could try: `result = [my_func() for i in range(1000)]`, it is already fast enough

Comment: I see your point but I want to use numpy for this particular example, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as  np
def my_func(arr):
  rvs = np.random.random(size=3)
  return rvs[2] - rvs[1]

vfunc = np.vectorize(my_func)
result = []
result.append(vfunc([1]*1000))
print(result)
```

Hope it hepls

**Explanation**:

np.vectorize is vectorizing the function. In normal cases you will pass a numpy array to a function that performs some task on its elements, but here I just passed an anonymous list for the function to be executed 1000 times rest is as you were doing

Comment: Be aware that this basically corresponds to wrapping the supplied `my_func` in a for loop. No strict-sense vectorization is happening here. See the notes in https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html